# function call is passed over before having the chance to set important data

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, request

So I have this function in node.js that gets the external IP by grabbing it from `https://icanhazip.com/` (handy website, check it out), but when the request is called it isn't allowed to finish before `return` is called. Here is the code:

```
var request = require('request');
var get_ext_ip = function(){
    var _ip; //Initialize a return variable

    //Launch an HTTPS request to a simple service that shows IP of client
    //The callback function isn't allowed to finish.
    request('https://icanhazip.com', function(error, response, body){
        _ip = body; //when finished store the response in the variable that is going to be returned.
    });

    //Return
    return _ip;
}

var ip = get_ext_ip();
console.log(ip); //undefined
```

So I guess, the question here is: how do I make this script wait for that callback function to finish before returning a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the asynchronous nature of I/O requests in Node: the function `get_ext_ip` returns before the request has finished.

One of the methods of handling this is to pass a callback function which will get called when the request is done:

```
var request = require('request');
var get_ext_ip = function(callback) {
  request('https://icanhazip.com', function(error, response, body) {
    callback(error, body);
  });
}

get_ext_ip(function(err, ip) {
  if (err)
    console.log('an error occurred:', error);
  else
    console.log(ip);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `async series` library [here](https://github.com/caolan/async#series), sample here

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        // do some stuff ...
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback){
        // do some more stuff ...
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
});


// an example using an object instead of an array
async.series({
    one: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 1);
        }, 200);
    },
    two: function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 2);
        }, 100);
    }
},
function(err, results) {
    // results is now equal to: {one: 1, two: 2}
});
```

Also, take a look at this question, [Idiomatic way to wait for multiple callbacks in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172244/idiomatic-way-to-wait-for-multiple-callbacks-in-node-js)