# Return a value from an event emitter callback

Tags: javascript, node-postgres

I am using the postgresql module 'pg' in node. I would like to do some processing when a row is returned from the database, but I do not know how to return the value to the calling function.

```
var caller = function(){
    var query = client.query(qString);
    query.on('row', function(row){
        if (row.foo == bar) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

when I call:

```
var boo = caller();
```

I want boo to equal the returned bool of the callback.

I tried to declare a variable uninitialized and then assign the value of the returned bool,

```
var caller = function(){
    var fido;
    var query = client.query(qString);
    query.on('row', function(row){
        if (row.foo == bar) {
            fido = true;
        } else {
            fido =  false;
        }
    }
    return fido;
};
```

but the function doesn't wait until 'pg' returns a row. This causes the returned variable to be returned undefined. I'm thinking I need to call part of this synchronously so the assigning of the variable happens before the function returns it, but I'm not sure how to do this for a normal function.

EDIT:

Enough with the pseudo code. I am new to Node and trying to get better at asking questions. This is a application for a class I am in. I wrote most of it in python with web.py and because of a conflict with the angular.js framework and re-writing in node.js, which I don't have much experience with. The part I'm having trouble with is the authenticating users. Here is the module that gets called.

```
var postAuth = function(params, callback){
    var user = params['username'];
    var pass = params['password'];
    var result;
    util['dispatch']['auth'](user, function(blah){
        if (pass == blah) {
            result = true;
        } else {
            result = false;
        }
    });
    console.log(result);
    return callback(200, "OK", {}, result);
}
```

and the function that gets the password from the DB for the username:

```
var auth = function(user, callback) {
    client.connect();
    var qString = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='" + user + "'";
    var query = client.query(qString);
    query.on('row', function(row) {
            callback(row.password);
    }); 
};
```

I know that this is an insecure way to authenticate. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. I am trying to return a bool based on whether or not the password matches.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/16021543/893780 where I answered a similar question.

Comment: See edit, Still returning undefined.

Comment: About your edit: `quecall` doesn't return a value, so `returned` is of course `undefined`. You should pass a callback into `caller`, exactly as @robertklep suggests.

Comment: see edit: added real code from my application instead of pseudo code.

Comment: Thanks for your help ended baking the utilities file with the db connection in with my auth scripts to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make asynchronous functions synchronous (which also means returning values from asynchronous functions – usually – has no effect).

A common solution to handle the results of an asynchronous function is to pass a callback function which gets called when the results are available:

```
var caller = function(callback) {
  var query = client.query(qString);
  query.on('row', function(row){
    callback(row.foo == bar);
  }
};

// and to call it:
caller(function(result) {
  console.log('I received a result:', result);
});
```

The callback function will get called one row at a time.

Comment: I have no problem doing console.log(). The problem I am having is returning the value to function that called it. This is being called from another module.

Comment: I understand, but I'm showing you how to deal with asynchronous functions, from which you can't return values. So the processing you need to do has to take place in a callback *somehow*. You can use modules like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [node-promise](https://github.com/kriszyp/node-promise) to make handling this sort of workflow easier.

Answer (score 0):

I show how to return a promise from an event emitter in this blog post https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/promisify-event-emitter/

Comment: while this may be correct, the [answering guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) instruct you to "add context around the link" and "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link", which you neglected to do

Comment: Link dead - domain for sale.