# Nodejs step through array and finish each step before moving on

Tags: node.js

I'm having troubles processing a queue that I've got stored in Redis.

Basically the queue in Redis is a simple array of IDs that I want to step through one by one.

My current code:

```
async.forEach(data, function(n, done) {
    redisClient.hgetall("visitor:" + n, function(err, visitor) {
        if (visitor != null) {
            agentOnlineCheck(visitor['userID'], function(online) {
                if (online == true) {
                    console.log("We are done with this item, move on to the next");
                } else {
                    console.log("We are done with this item, move on to the next");
                }
            });

        } else {
            console.log("We are done with this item, move on to the next");
        }
    });
}, function() {
    console.log("I want this to fire when all items in data are finished");
});
```

I use the `async` library and above the var `data` represents an array such as:

```
['232323', '232423', '23232']
```

I want to loop through the array but one ID at a time. And not move on to the next ID until the previous one has run through all the callbacks.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Idiomatic way to wait for multiple callbacks in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172244/idiomatic-way-to-wait-for-multiple-callbacks-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async.eachSeries` instead of `async.forEach`.

c.f.: https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries