# How to append two results of query in one json in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Following is my code of in node.js i would like to know how to append two results of query in one json and send the json in response.

```
        router.get("/get-meta", function(req, res, next){

    connection.query("select id, country_name from country", function (error, results) {

        if (error) res.json({"status": "failed", "message": error.message});
        else res.send(JSON.stringify({ results }));
    });
    connection.query("select id, currency from currency", function (error, results2) {

        if (error) res.json({"status": "failed", "message": error.message});
        else res.send(JSON.stringify({ results2 }));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use async.parallel to send parallel requests.the result of async.parallel will be an array of results (which will solve your problem)

```
var async = require('async')

router.get("/get-meta", function(req, res, next){

    async.parallel([
        function(callback){
            connection.query("select id, country_name from country", function (error, result1) {
                callback(error,result1)
            });
        },
        function(callback){
            connection.query("select id, currency from currency", function (error, result2) {
                callback(error,result2)
            });
        }

        ],function(err,results){
            if(err){
                res.json({"status": "failed", "message": error.message})
            }else{
                res.send(JSON.stringify(results)); //both result1 and result2 will be in results
            }
        })
});
```

Comment: How can I give heading to each result-set while returning response?
For example i am getting data like: 
[[{"id":1,"country_name":"Pakistan"}],[{"id":1,"currency":"PKR"}]] 
to
[country: [{"id":1,"country_name":"Pakistan"}], currency:[{"id":1,"currency":"PKR"}]]

Comment: you cannot specify headers ,but the results will be in order.so you can asume the results of query1( first function) will be in `results[0]` and query2 will be in `results[1]` and so on

Comment: and can we use some data from result1 in second function?

Comment: it is parallel function both functions will run together so you cannot use data from one func. in another,but you want such operation you can use `async.waterfall` (but this will run your  functions in series)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should find a method to `await` for two **async** operation to finished, and then **concat** the results. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551499/simplest-way-to-wait-some-asynchronous-tasks-complete-in-javascript) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172244/idiomatic-way-to-wait-for-multiple-callbacks-in-node-js)

You should use `concat` method.

Here is an example:

```js
var json1 = [{'name': "doug", 'id':5}];
var json2 = [{'name': "goud", 'id':1}];
json1 = json1.concat(json2);
console.log(json1);
```

Comment: Appreciate your efforts but the reference links you provided was confusing and complicated. But thanks though.